# Waiting for /dev/sda1 to become available, with timeout, in shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have Linux image that on boot, needs to execute a script that will be located on a plugged in thumbdrive. Here is what I have.

```
mkdir /mnt/usb
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb
cd /mnt/usb/DMS
cp script.sh /
chmod +x /script.sh
/bin/sh /script.sh
```

This script is added late in the sysvinit scripts. It works with most drives, however, some drives take a while to get recognized. That means my script will fail, because `/dev/sda1` isn't available yet.

How do I modify this shell script to perform a while/wait on the device, with a timeout if none is ever found.

Pseudo code:

```
counter = 1
while /dev/sda1 not present
   sleep 100
   counter++
   if counter is 50
      exit # no drive ever found
   endif
endwhile

# do stuff with plugged in drive, mount it, whatever
```

How do I perform something like this in a shell script?

Answer (score 3):

Translating you pseudo-code directly into shell get

```
#!/bin/sh
counter=0

while [ ! -e /dev/sda1 ]; do
    sleep 100
    counter=$((counter + 1))
    if [ $counter -ge 50 ]; then
        exit
    fi
done
```

Optionally you can change `-e /dev/sda1` to `-b /dev/sda1` to check for block device.

Comment: Why would I want to check for a block device, instead of just using ```-e```?

Comment: This is necessary primarily for elaborate scripts that get argument from command line and want to ensure that they deal with block device not just ordinary file.

Comment: NOTE: Not all USB sticks are mountable using this block device.  I have come across some that in your example you'd be mounting as /dev/sda (i.e. no partition table).